# Check the product in the cart from which category is and show message

Tags: wp-query, categories

I want to check the product in cart from which category is and if is from Category X to show some message.

So far I've done this and I've placed it in `checkout.php`

```
$categories = array('cat' => '39');
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
    if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
        $found = true; // Set to true
        break; // Stop the loop
    }
}        
if ( $found ) {
   do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals' );
}   
else {
    echo "Product from category X";
}
```

Sadly, here I see the `else { echo "Product from category X"; }` no matter if the product is from Category X or no.

`var_dump($found);` return `NULL`

Comment: Try using `$categories = array( 39 );` ?

Comment: Still same, no matter what product is in the cart I see `else` block and `$found` is `NULL`

Comment: Hm, after few refreshes and tests now it is working with `$categories = array( 39 );`. Thanks